# angularjs cache compiled html

Tags: html, angularjs, caching

I am working on a project where we are starting to add in angularjs. I have a page where I am injecting some html into the page from an $http request. When I get the data back I compile it and insert it into the document. This all works. The problem I have is it is a large amount of html that has to be inserted into the site. If I save the html in a variable or cache (cacheFactory) I can then just recompile it and add it again. This works but the problem is when it $compiles it it makes the page non-responsive for a second or 2.

What I want to know is if I can cache the $compile html and just reuse that? What I have been trying so far does not work.

```
promise.then(function(data)) {
    cacheService.put("testData", $compile(data)($scope));
    addTestData();

}};

function addTestData() {
    $("#placeHolder").empty().html(cacheService.get("testData"));
}
```

Comment: answer would depend on whether scope will change, and the compiled html would be impacted by changes.

Comment: If the outside scope changes I am not worried about that. Just want to be able to insert the compiled html again with ought the site hanging for those 2 seconds.